# Polynomials on the space $L^2(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C})$

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-numbers, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

This may seem like a strange question but what would be the basis functions of a space $L^2(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C})$? Is there any equivalent to the Hermite Functions? Alternatively, am I thinking about it the wrong way and one should consider $L^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$ as functions that satisfy $f(x), g(x)$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, $|| f(x) + i g(x)||_{L^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})} \leq \infty $? where $L^2(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C})$ has the conjugation on the first argument of the inner product.

I ask this because to test the question, is there no such thing as a self-adjoint operator with complex eigenvectors? Please answer my first question first to help me build an intuition!

Best wishes,

Catherine

Comment: $L^2$ is usually meant to be the complex valued functions, often not specified because it really doesn't change anything to look at the real valued or complex valued functions (except that we take the complex conjugate of one function in the inner product)

Comment: but what would an example of a set of basis vectors be?

Comment: Any orthogonal basis of the real valued $L^2$ is also an orthogonal basis of the complex valued $L^2$

Comment: but can you have a basis with complex eigenvectors? I ask because what if you have eigenvectors corresponding to complex eigenvalues... I know a basis is formed under certain conditions, but is it possible to have a basis in L^2(R,C)

Comment: What is your concrete problem ? Normal (compact) operators satisfy the spectral theorem while still having a complex spectrum.

Comment: And what if the operator is just non-self-adjoint? But in the normal case, they satisfy the spectral theorem coverning what space $L^2(R,C)$ or $L^2(R)$ because the mapping itself is a function in $L^2(R,C)$... does that mean all functions that take the real line to the complex plane can be expressed in the eigenvectors of normaloperators?

Comment: I think I've gotten confused with notation... does $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ mean the functions mapping $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ or functions that take inputs of the entire real line, i.e. have the real line as their domains?

Comment: $L^2(\Bbb{R})$ is the set of functions $f: \Bbb{R}\to K$ "measurable" such that $\int_\Bbb{R} |f(x)|^2dx <\infty$, where $K$ is either $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$ depending on the context, and measurable is needed to make sense to $\int_\Bbb{R} |f(x)|^2dx$ as a Lebesgue integral. In most cases in analysis $f$ will be a continuous function away from a countable set of points, like $e^{-x^2} \log |x|$, so $\int_\Bbb{R} |f(x)|^2dx$ will be an improper Riemann integral.